# No REMOTES left on Git; Still branch -r shows some; PRUNE have been tried - no luck

Tags: git

I am performing housekeeping in my project. As I have messed things a bit,
I have had to manually deleted all REMOTES (I have had two of them) in `.git\config`.

Still `git branch -r` shows two remote branches, while there should be none of them.

How to clean them up?

I have already tried to add that rogue_remote back and `git remote prune rogue_remote`.
No luck.

Any hints?

Comment: Does `git remote prune origin` help? Just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> manually deleted all REMOTES

**manually** was a mistake. The command should have been

```
git remote rm rogue_remote
```

Now you need to use plumbing (low-level) commands:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/rogue_remote/master
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref).

Answer (score 1):

> I have had to manually deleted all REMOTES (I have had two of them) in `.git\config.`

If you'd used `git remote remove` on  them it'd have cleaned up the tracking refs, but since you're doing it manually you have to take care of the details yourself.